# tensorflow tf.data.experimental.rejection_resample does not achieve target distribution even with a seed value

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to test rejection sampling with the following code. 
This is the result I got:

```
target_dist [0.5, 0.5] 
initial distribution [0.8333333333333334, 0.16666666666666666]
result counts [1500, 600] 
final dist 0.7142857142857143 0.2857142857142857
```

The final distribution does not reflect the target distribution I set.

Any idea?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
# everything is based on tensorflow 2.0
tf.random.set_seed(2342)


def map2label(sample):
    return tf.cast(tf.math.equal(sample, 2), tf.int32)

np_data = np.array([0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2])
target_dist = [0.5, 0.5]
init_dist = [(np_data.shape[0]-3)/np_data.shape[0], 3/np_data.shape[0]]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np_data)
rej = tf.data.experimental.rejection_resample(map2label, target_dist, init_dist, 2342)   # set seed explicitly
dataset = dataset.apply(rej)

bucket_counts = [0, 0]
for i in range(100):
    for data in dataset:
        class_id, data_content = data
        bucket_counts[class_id.numpy()] += 1

print("This is your target_dist", target_dist, "This is your initial distribution", init_dist)
print("This is your result counts", bucket_counts,
      "This is your final dist", bucket_counts[0] / np.sum(bucket_counts), bucket_counts[1] / np.sum(bucket_counts))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather a workaround than a solution to solve the rejection sampling problem here. I used my own undersampling algorithm than rejection sampling. It works differently, however, it serves the purpose. I'll keep this question here, as rejection sampling will be more efficient in some situation so this is still helpful to others.

```
# everything below is tensorflow 2.0
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import numpy as np
from termcolor import colored

seed = 1341
tf.random.set_seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)

# generate data and distribution
init_dist = [0.9, 0.1]
num_per_class = np.random.multinomial(10000, init_dist)
np_data = np.hstack((np.zeros(num_per_class[0], dtype=np.int32),
                     np.ones(num_per_class[1], dtype=np.int32)))
np.random.shuffle(np_data)
batch_size = 40
epochs = 1
target_dist = np.array([0.5, 0.5], dtype=np.float32)
number_of_positives = np.sum(np_data)
number_of_negatives = np_data.shape[0] - number_of_positives
number_of_examples = np_data.shape[0]
all_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np_data)

def filter(dist, seed=seed):
    # create a uniform distribution
    tf.random.set_seed(seed)
    normal = tfp.distributions.Uniform(low=0, high=1.0)
    def _filter(sample):
        # explanation: uniform distribution has 60% chance larger than 0.4
        # so if you want to draw a sample at 60% chance, your tocken
        # needs to be larger than (1 - 60%)
        tocken = normal.sample()
        return tf.cast(tocken > (1 - dist[tf.cast(sample, tf.int32)]), tf.bool)
    return _filter

# Undersampling
drawing_prob = np.min(init_dist) / np.array(init_dist)
dist = tf.constant(drawing_prob, tf.float32)
method2_dataset = all_dataset.filter(filter(dist))
method2_dataset = method2_dataset.batch(batch_size)

# Verify dataset is balanced

def compute_distribution(dataset, epochs, batch_size):
    data_receives = []
    # count stats to verify both batch distribution and total distribution
    bucket_counts = [0, 0]
    batch_counts = []
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        data_receives.append([])
        for data_contents in dataset:
            batch_count = [0, 0]
            for j in range(batch_size):
                try:
                    data_content = data_contents.numpy()[j]
                    data_receives[epoch].append(data_content)
                    bucket_counts[data_content] += 1
                    batch_count[data_content] += 1
                except IndexError:
                    break
            batch_counts.append(batch_count)

    # Batch distribution
    for bid, batch in enumerate(batch_counts):
        print("batch %03d, batch count [%02d, %02d], 
               batch distribution [%02.2f, %02.2f]"
               % (bid, batch[0], batch[1], batch[0] / np.sum(batch),
                  batch[1] / np.sum(batch)))

    # Total distribution
    print(colored("result counts [%d %d] 
                   final distribution [%02.2f, %02.2f]"
          % (bucket_counts[0], bucket_counts[1],
          bucket_counts[0] / np.sum(bucket_counts), 
          bucket_counts[1] / np.sum(bucket_counts)),
          "green"))

    # check if each epoch produces the same order
    for i in range(len(data_receives)-1):
        if not np.array_equal(np.array(data_receives[i]),
                              np.array(data_receives[i+1])):
            raise ValueError("Order not preserved.")
    if epochs > 1:
        print(colored("Yes, order is preserved.", "green"))

compute_distribution(method2_dataset, epochs, batch_size)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following changes made the code work for me:

1. repeat the dataset infinitely (or by a huge factor, e.g. 1000)
   by using: shuffle = tf.data.experimental.shuffle_and_repeat(1, count=1000)
2. cut the infinite set back to the desired length by using: dataset = dataset.take(30)
   To obtain good results I had to take at least 30 samples. Looks like the original
   18 samples of np_data are simply not large enough.
3. removing the init_dist improved the balacing significantly

---

```
target_dist [0.5, 0.5]
initial distribution [0.8333333333333334, 0.16666666666666666]
result counts [1500, 1500]
final dist 0.5 0.5
```

---

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# everything is based on tensorflow 2.0
tf.random.set_seed(2342)


def map2label(sample):
    return tf.cast(tf.math.equal(sample, 2), tf.int32)


np_data = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2])
target_dist = [0.5, 0.5]
init_dist = [(np_data.shape[0] - 3) / np_data.shape[0], 3 / np_data.shape[0]]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np_data)
shuffle = tf.data.experimental.shuffle_and_repeat(1, count=1000)
rej = tf.data.experimental.rejection_resample(map2label, target_dist, seed=2342)  # set seed explicitly
dataset = dataset.apply(shuffle).apply(rej)
dataset = dataset.take(30)

bucket_counts = [0, 0]
for i in range(100):
    for data in dataset:
        class_id, data_content = data
        bucket_counts[class_id.numpy()] += 1

print("This is your target_dist", target_dist, "This is your initial distribution", init_dist)
print("This is your result counts", bucket_counts,
      "This is your final dist", bucket_counts[0] / np.sum(bucket_counts), bucket_counts[1] / np.sum(bucket_counts))
```

Answer (score 1):

ok here is how i do it

```
nn = 0
for _ in ds: nn +=1
ds_per_class = [ds.repeat().filter(lambda inp,tar: tar==kk) for kk in range(class_nn)]
ds = tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets(ds_per_class).take(nn)
```

the key is splitting in list-of-datasets by class with filter, then use sample_from_dataset to get uniform distro, which requires to act on infinite datasets, thus we do repeat() before

we need to get initial ds.len nn to do take(nn) to keep the original epoch size, if we want to still be consistent in model.fit() - but otherwise that's not necessary if we don't care about epoch len (could say take(1000) for instance).